# What do you call the line/s of code that declare that a class or function is a template?

Tags: c++

I'm writing some macros which declare template types and I'm a bit stumped for terminology. To illustrate, take the following example:

```
// template class declaration
template <typename A, typename B> // what is this called?
class A;
```

My question is: **What is the name of the line above `class A`**?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply part of the [class declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5kx78b.aspx).

When you *declare* a type, you essentially say "this is a type." Compared to the *definition* which provides the contents of the type: its data members and member functions (although those functions may themselves be declarations, with the definitions separate).

That the declaration you provided involves a template does not change this fact, nor does the fact that they are on separate lines in the file. The newline is irrelevant here: the important thing is what occurs from the beginning of the statement to its end (the semicolon).

Comment: So then what is the name you would give to the difference between `template <typename X> class A;` and `class A;`? There's no name for it?

Comment: The first is a template class, the second is not. If there is a name for it, it is not something I am familiar with or can locate with a web search.

Comment: Wouldn't the `template< blah, blah >` be called the "template argument list"?

Comment: That makes sense, but I was not able to find an "official" name nor did Rufflewind in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there doesn't seem to be an official name for it.

In the C++ standard, the grammar for a template declaration is:

```
template-declaration:
    "template" "<" template-parameter-list ">" declaration
```

so it doesn't actually designate a name for the `template<...>` part.